# exercice analysis; inverse theorem, implicit function theorem, locally immersions and submersions, post theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Could anyone help me find lists of exercises (in books or other materials) analysis in R for a qualification examination. Threads 0) differentiability in R 1) the inverse function theorem 2) implicit function theorem 3) locally immersions and submersions 4) the rank theorem

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0-2 can be found in Charles Pugh's "Real Mathematical Analysis"

3 can be found in Guilleman and Pollack's "Differential Topology" in the beginning chapters

4 can be found in Loring Tu's "An Introduction to Manifolds"